# Resizing the vertices inside xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

Does anyone know how to resize the names of entries which appear as vertices inside `\xymatrix`? I have huge commuative cubes with more then 40 inner or outer vertices and when these names become too large then one cannot distinguish the edges of diagrams between them...

Answer (score 1):

here's an approach that's rather a hack, as it must be applied manually to every vertex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\newcommand{\smxylabel}[1]{{\text{\small$#1$}}}

\begin{document}
This diagram has normal-sized labels.
\[
\xymatrix{%
  V_1 \ar[d]_\tau \ar[r]^{\rho_1(g) } & V_1 \ar[d]^\tau \\
  V_2             \ar[r]^{\rho_2(g) } & V_2
}
\]

This diagram has ``smallified'' labels, hard coded.
\[
\xymatrix{%
  \text{\small$V_1$} \ar[d]_{\text{\small$\tau$}} \ar[r]^{\text{\small$\rho_1(g)$} }
    & \text{\small$V_1$} \ar[d]^{\text{\small$\tau$}} \\
  \text{\small$V_2$}  \ar[r]^{\text{\small$\rho_2(g)$} }
    & \text{\small$V_2$}
}
\]

This diagram uses a macro to shrink the labels.
\[
\xymatrix{%
  \smxylabel{V_1} \ar[d]_{\smxylabel{\tau}} \ar[r]^{\smxylabel{\rho_1(g)} }
   & \smxylabel{V_1} \ar[d]^{\smxylabel{\tau}} \\
  \smxylabel{V_2}  \ar[r]^{\smxylabel{\rho_2(g)} }
   & \smxylabel{V_2}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

**edit**: the original poster asks whether it's possible to use `\objectbox`.  i'm not familiar with that command, and have never used it, but it's definitely available in `xypic`.

the way it's defined appears to correspond reasonably well to the concept of my hack.  so i think it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer very much! It improves a solution of my problem. Do you know may I also use size modifiers using `\objectbox`?